# Python 3 not reading path of file - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

Here is the Project structure -

MAIN Project FOLDER:

- `file1.py`
- `Directory1`

  - `testFile.py`

`file1.py` is in the Main Project folder.

`testFile.py` is under `Directory1`.

I need to import `file1.py` into `testFile.py`.

If I just add
`import file1` in `testFile.py`, it gives me error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'`

Comment: There is a custom exception. I'm trying to import ``` from file1 import excName```

Comment: Try importing with with complete path

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `path` to the `sys.path` in testFile.py, can you try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
import file1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where exactly should I add this piece of code? In testFile.py? In testFile.py, I get the error on line ``` import file.py```. Should I write these 2 lines before ``` import file.py```?